# What if something that destroyed Horcruxes were made into a Horcrux?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux, basilisk

If you made a Horcrux something that destroyed Horcruxes like a basilisk fang, what would be the result? Could it still be destroyed by venom?

Comment: If memory serves, it's basilisk *venom* that destroys the diary. The structure of the tooth could presumably be made into a horcrux but it would be vulnerable to being pierced with another basilisk tooth.

Comment: It would seem that a basilisk fang horcrux could be destroyed with the Sword of Griffindor, but that's just a guess.

Comment: That's good. This question will probably get an answer. What about the phoenix one?

Answer (score 5):

### It would probably be vulnerable to destruction, but not from itself

According to Hermione, the indestructibility of Horcruxes comes from the powerful spells that their creators lay on them, which repair any damage that the Horcruxes incur. One of the only things that is sufficiently destructive is basilisk venom.

> “Yes,” said Hermione, now turning the fragile pages as if examining
> rotting entrails. “**because it warns Dark wizards how strong they have
> to make the enchantments on them**. From all that I’ve read, what Harry
> did to Riddle’s diary was one of the really foolproof ways of
> destroying a Horcrux.”
>
> “What, stabbing it with a basilisk fang?” asked Harry.
>
> “Oh well, lucky we’ve got such a large supply of basilisk fangs,
> then,” said Ron. “I was wondering what we were going to do with them.”
>
> “It doesn’t have to be a basilisk fang,” said Hermione patiently. “**It
> has to be something so destructive that the Horcrux can’t repair
> itself.** Basilisk venom only has one antidote, and it’s incredibly
> rare—”
>
> “—phoenix tears,” said Harry, nodding.
>
> “Exactly,” said Hermione, “Our problem is that the are very few
> substances as destructive as basilisk venom, and they’re all dangerous
> to carry around with you. That’s a problem we’re going to have to
> solve though, because **ripping, smashing, or crushing a Horcrux won’t
> do the trick. You’ve got to put it beyond magical repair.**”
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*

Note that  the venom is effective because it is so destructive, magically so, that the Horcrux is incapable of repairing itself.

Hermione explicitly frames survival of the Horcrux in terms of the physical survival of the container:

> “But it’s the other way round with a Horcrux.
> The fragment of soul
> inside it **depends on it’s container, its enchanted body, for survival,
> It can’t exist without it.”**
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*

Of course, basilisk venom does not eat through a basilisk's fang, so we must assume the basilisk is immune. As such, basilisk venom would not physically damage the Horcrux, which Hermione informs us is what leads to its destruction.

However, the Horcrux could still be destroyed. Basilisk venom is one of only a few things that destroy Horcruxes, but there are others.

> “It must have been Fiendfyre!” whimpered Hermione, her eyes on the
> broken piece.
>
> “Sorry?”
>
> “Fiendfyre-cursed fire—it’s one of the substances that destroy
> Horcruxes, but I would never, ever have dared use it, it’s so
> dangerous—how did Crabbe know how to—?"
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*

Since at least some of these options are spells (which cannot be made into Horcruxes), presumably any Horcrux can still be destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, it could probably be destroyed just as before.**

It's hard for anything to destroy *itself* - for instance, a tooth can't pierce itself, and a sword can't chop itself. But there's no reason to think that, for instance, a basilisk-fang Horcrux couldn't be destroyed by *another* basilisk fang.

After all, it's not the physical material of the Horcrux that you're destroying when you stab it with a basilisk fang or the Sword of Gryffindor. It's the Dark magic that binds the fragment of soul within it and protects the item from most physical harm which is being destroyed. Stabbing a Horcrux with a basilisk fang should break the spell that makes it a Horcrux regardless of whether the item itself is a locket, a snake, a diary, or another basilisk fang.